# Is there a firebug-like tool for IE6?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firebug for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351/firebug-for-ie)

I have no tool to inspect into DOM in IE6 now.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351/firebug-for-ie

Comment: Alert debugging is the _only_ way. Purely out of choice, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

Answer (score 3):

Does the IE Developer Toolbar help with what you're trying to accomplish?
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck in the past with [IEWatch](http://www.iewatch.com/). (but I haven't done web development in awhile, so I'm not sure if it does the same things as Firebug.)

Answer (score 0):

is this because you're trying to actually test in IE6, or because you're stuck in it?

if it's the latter, I wonder if you can install the chrome frame and use the inspector that comes with chrome (is the inspector included in the frame? I would assume so..) to do your DOM inspection.