# Is there a tool like Firebug available for IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a tool like Firebug besides Firebug for IE and Developers toolbar.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of issues are you trying to solve?

Comment: You want something like firebug but not firebug ? why, if i may ask ?

Comment: Because Firebug for IE is very very Verbose.

Comment: Opera browser has built-in Opera Dragonfly, which is Firebug for Opera. Try Firebug lite for IE or Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar from Microsotf

Comment: And Developers toolbar for IE8 laborious.
For Every element to test, every time one has to select the menu option,......

Comment: What's wrong with the developer toolbar? It's installed with IE8 and has been improved for IE9 developer preview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebug for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351/firebug-for-ie)

Comment: @OregonGhost: I'll tell you what's wrong with it, my lad. 'E's dead, that's what's wrong with it! [/python] Sorry, couldn't resist ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, some of us are still stuck coding to IE because that's the corporate standard.  *sigh*

Answer (score 4):

I've used [MS's IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) before and have found it useful.

Comment: That's like comparing a land rover to a skateboard. A skateboard is great if it's all you've got but it's not gonna go the distance if you're trying to get from Paris to Dakar in a hurry...

Comment: Actually, it is a very useful tool.  Its not quite as featureful as firebug but its nothing to be scoffed at either.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 has a quite good Firebug lookalike called Developer Tools, built-in (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to activate it).

Answer (score 1):

There's [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/?langage=en), but be warned... it's as crap as IE is.

Firebug lite gets my vote.

This topic is [discussed here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887471/is-there-any-other-tool-better-than-firebug-on-any-other-browsers/1887478#1887478).