# Is there any Developer tool like FireBug for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firebug for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351/firebug-for-ie)

I am looking for web developer tool like FireBug for IE for inspecting html elements? Things which works fine in FireFox/Crome does not work in IE? some works fine in IE8 not in IE7 ? why it is so...?

Answer (score 18):

Try pressing "F12" on your browser. It's a tool for developers that works nearly as same as firebug.

Comment: for me on pressing f12 nothing works!

Comment: Get your F12 button checked ^.^

Comment: Nearly the same except for not being even nearly at all the same.

Comment: There is always a way how to get around this issue, watch the video and you will be able to install firebug in 2 mins.[install firebug on ie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLJ2RaNZ22E)  Good luck.

Comment: try sticking a fork in your eye.  Its nearly the same as f12 dev tool

Answer (score 4):

[Internet Explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) is the closest you get in the browser.