# Looking for developers plugin for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am having hard time with a website design in IE. its actually working fine in mozilla, chrome, opera and safari but very messy in IE. so my question "Is there any plugin like **firebug** for **IE**"?.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/8351/778687

Answer (score 6):

For IE9+, just hit F12 for developer tools.

For older IE (8 and below), you got [Debug Bar](http://www.debugbar.com/) or [Microsoft Script Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Editor) which ships with Office 2003 (weird isn't it? why debugging tools ship with office tools. MS is really weird)

Comment: Script debuggers come in handy when you're doing Office automation, FWIW.

Comment: @RizwanAshraf it's better to address that in another question.

Comment: i asked an other question .. please can you check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118155/ie-issuses-causing

Comment: so downvoter, what can you say?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to an extent. Take a look here for more info - http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Good luck and have fun with IE!

Comment: Lets all bond over our mutual hatred of IE

Answer (score 1):

IE 9 has development tools similar to Firebug. Just press F12

Answer (score 0):

not that I'm aware of, but you can turn on script debugging if that helps. this link is old but may still be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359