# Measuring Javascript performance in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, profiling

I have a webpage that heavily uses Javascript (AJAX requests, Google Maps API, HTML building, etc) and the page brings my PC to its knees whenever opened in Internet Explorer. I'm looking for some tools to help me find out which functions are taking the most time to finish. I have some basic profiling javascript functions, but those don't help much considering I don't know what function specifically is being slow. The tool has to be for IE, as the page runs fine in other browsers.

Comment: You may want to look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404/javascript-troubleshooting-tools-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might actually want to check out the Developer tools that come with IE8.  I know js debugging and profiling are part of it.

Comment: And actually great part of it.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for in functionality :)

Answer (score 2):

For JavaScript, XmlHttpRequest, DOM Access, Rendering Times and Network traffic for IE6, 7 & 8 you can use the free [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [YUI Profiler](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/).