# What is the best way to profile my javascript code ?

Tags: javascript

I am interested in know how much memory my JavaScript code running inside a browser is consuming and how it is increasing decreasing with time. How do I do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to profile javascript execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FireFox then [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) is perfect for this application. I'd highly recommend it for debugging javascript in browser.

[StackOverflow: what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)

Looks like this would be a good answer for you too.

Answer (score 3):

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

`Firebug` includes a `powerful JavaScript debugger` that lets you pause execution at any time and see what each variable looked like at that moment. If your code is a little sluggish, use the JavaScript `profiler to measure performance` and find bottlenecks fast.

```
Edit : You may refer previously answered questions on stackoverflow.
```

[JavaScript Profiler in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/javascript-profiler-in-ie)

[Javascript memory profiler for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171565/javascript-memory-profiler-for-firefox)

[Measuring Javascript performance in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829615/measuring-javascript-performance-in-ie)

[How to profile and and get Javascript performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140716/how-to-profile-and-and-get-javascript-performance)

http://www.imnmotion.com/documents/html/technical/dhtml/jsprof.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser...
If you're using Chrome (that's what i'm using...):

- Open up the page
- Right click anywhere -> Inspect element (opens up Dev toolbar)
- Go to Profiles tab
- Click the little "recording" icon (cirle) at the bottom of the screen (4th button)
- When it's read it's indicating it's recording
- Do your thing
- Click the rec button again
- enjoy the statistics