# framework to performance test javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, performance-testing

I am currently implementing a module observer pattern to a large scale web application that has a large dependency on javascript. I have introduced unit testing of each of the modules which I find very beneficial in capturing any issues with my javascript.

I would now also like to look at the possibility of performance testing my javascript. Are there any frameworks available where I can set up performance test for my javascript files?

Comment: this was just asked this morning...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to profile my javascript code ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514722/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Previous question is asking for profiling, I am looking for a framework to performance test javascript

Answer (score 4):

I'm familiar with the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/faq) service for javascript performance testing.  It is based on the [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) benchmarking library.  You could use use either depending upon the details of what you're looking for.