# How do I find out why my Javascript is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover, conflict

Are there any tricks to understand why, I was just running my website on Joomla - and ends up I didn't need the CMS anymore so I converted it all over to an independent format it was working fine before in IE (So javascript is turned on and working) however now when I go to the page it only functions properly in every other browser.

Mouseover events such as image changeing and show/hide divs on mouseover aren't working anymore.... I checked out Adobe BrowserLab but it seems useless...

Are there any Trips/Tricks I can use to find out why?

http://www.chessfactory.com

Comment: Check the console log for errors?

Comment: Make sure you cleared your cache in IE, if it was around the same time you made the change.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what problems you are trying to solve but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404/javascript-troubleshooting-tools-in-ie) may be helpful.

Also, see [this introduction to the IE developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: if I knew I'd tell ya - lol... the site is in the topic, OnMouseOver of the buttons 3" etc, its supposed to swap images, and un-hide a div..... but it dosent do either... all other browsers work.  Firebug is firefox only right? it works in firefox...

Answer (score 0):

[Internet Explorer 9 Developer Tools Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Press f12 for developer tools. Tried clearing your [cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache).