# Navigation menu doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hello I'm not hundred percent sure if this is a css cross browser issue or jquery cross browser issue.

Basically the Navigation links only work on the home page and not on any other pages in Internet Explorer.
All other browsers are fine.
I don't know what the problem is, I have suspected that the page content maybe over-lapping the navigation, because of some IE padding bug but it doesn't make sense because I it still recognises when I hover over the links, its just that they don't take you to other pages.

Would be very greatful for any advice or help, on how I can get started on fixing this.

The url is:
http://www.brooklyn-santiago.com/recovery/

Comment: There's an issue with `.split()` in IE, check your `custom.js` file `line 113`. Check the developer console in IE to see this error. `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference custom.js, line 113 character 8`
`

Comment: Check your Script Tab in IE. See this link (post with images) to get a little more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404/javascript-troubleshooting-tools-in-ie (scroll down a little)

Answer (score 1):

```
$et_bg.css('background-position-x').split(' ')
```

The statement above is where the issue is coming from. I was able to recreate your error.

```
et_bg_offset = ! is_ie ? $et_bg.css( 'backgroundPosition' ).split(' ') : $et_bg.css('background-position-x').split(' '),
```

The problem is that `'background-position-x'` should only by used in EI8 or lower, but you have it running for all versions of IE, which is causing it to break in IE9 and 10. if you change `is_ie` to only be true for EI8 or lower then this should work correctly.

Comment: Hello,@Schmalzy thsnks very much for your response.. I added this in the <head>                                                                                                             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">                        This has no visible effect. I am still getting this error in IE: Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 25
Char: 16
Code: 0
URI: http://www.brooklyn-santiago/recovery/wp-content/themes/Sky/js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js?ver=1.0

Comment: @PhillipAudleyBoothe I just changed my answer.... Remove the Meta Tags and try my new suggestion.